# Facebook Graph API with Koala Rails: error when adding dynamic "link" attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, hyperlink, koala

I've got a weird issue and I am pulling my hairs trying to find what's wrong:

I am posting on a group wall the following attachment but I can't post a dynamic link. See below:

This is working:

```
    @graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(params[:oauth_token])
    attachment = {
          "name" => "test",
          "link" => "http://test.herokuapp.com/tests/03095910",
          "description" => "click here"
        }
    @graph.put_wall_post("test", attachment, "528596717222285")
```

Whereas this does not work (with @test.url = "http://test.herokuapp.com/events/03095910")

```
    attachment = {
       "name" => "test",
       "link" => @test.url,
       "description" => "click here"
    }

    @graph.put_wall_post("test", attachment, "528596717222285")
```

I am desperate, I've tried everything so thanks in advance for your help!